# What is this thing's purpose?

Tags: garage, shelving, support, storage

So for part 3 in the [continuing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160578/can-someone-explain-this-wiring-configuration-to-me) [saga](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160497/can-someone-explain-how-this-makes-sense-electrically) of weird stuff in my house, the garage. In particular, this odd looking thing attached to the wall:
[image: Shelf???]
I thought it might be a shelf, but all of the supports are on top, which is an odd way to build a shelf. It is also too high up (about 7 feet off the ground) to be practical for storage. The cable and pulley looking thing might lead you to believe it was meant to be retractable, except, as you can see from the side view, it is quite firmly bolted into the masonry:
[image: Shelf??? side view]
The way the supports are placed, it looks designed to resist an upward force from below, but I have no idea what the intended use case for it could be.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the bottom of the board?

Comment: FYI, it looks like you have a hole that needs filled in that second picture’s rim joist

Comment: Something kludgey. Maybe a support for a flat, square digital TV antenna? The circular wear pattern on the bottom is weird. Drone landing pad?

Comment: The wear pattern was making me think speed bag, but I couldn’t get a good look which is why I asked for a pic

Comment: Punching bag support was what I thought as well, but I can't quite make out if there's a hole to mount one or not - if not, I have no idea,

Comment: Maybe a tire storage?

Comment: Ecnerwal nailed it, whatever it held was about the diameter of the chafing, and swung actively, most of that swinging being front to back.  It also had dynamic forces the original design didn't account for, hence the kludges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ecnerwal and @UnhandledExcepSean, I believe you are correct. Looking at this thing from below, I can see screw holes where a speed bag was probably mounted in the past.
[image: Bottom of shelf]
[image: Closeup on mounting holes]

Comment: I’m doubling down on a speed bag, not a punching bag. The bag was mounted in the middle and the wear was caused by the bag hitting the wood. The mounting difference is pretty big between a speed bag and a punching bag in my limited experience